# Silverlight: OnLoad not being called for Controls inside Popups

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, user-interface, popup

Has anyone seen this problem?

Is there a method I can call from my page to force the popup to initialize and load all inner controls?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a small example of your code?  Onload never called or not when you expected?

Comment: I'm using a custom control but the problem is that the OnLoad method is literally never called in my UserControl whenever I put it inside the Popup. If it's defined outside it is called normally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, as it stands I couldn't find any workaround to this bug and installing the latest version of Silverlight (version 4) fixed the problem.